# Problems with MKStoreKit and In App Purchases

Tags: ios, in-app, mkstorekit

I'm developing an app with In App Purchases using MKStoreKit Framework.

Everything goes fine, excepts I'm getting this message:

```
Review request cannot be checked now: (null)
```

I've checked and followed several guidelines, and I corrected an error with the provisioning profile. But now I'm getting this new error.

In itunes connect the app is created and every purchase is created too, but the status is waiting for review.

This status can cause the error? If this is the problem, how can I change the status of the purchases? Every field is filled and I have an app published under this apple account.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To test purchases in the sandboxed environment you need a test user account—your regular Apple ID won't do—and a submitted-and-developer-rejected binary. So submit an application binary for review (it doesn't need to be complete), and as soon as it has the 'Waiting for review' status reject it. You should then be able to test your IAP using your test account.

Answer (score 1):

How to properly test an in-app purchase:

1. Login to iTunes Connect
2. Click **Manage Users** (You need administrator privileges for this)
3. Click **Test User**
4. Create a new user with a bogus email address/other info
5. On your device, go to **Settings** > **iTunes and App Stores**
6. Log out of your current account. **Do not log into your test account yet!**
7. Run your app and proceed to purchase your IAP.
8. When it prompts you to log in, log into your test account you created.
9. You should get a message "Would you like to confirm...**[Environment: Sandbox]**"
10. Click yes.

If you got to this point, your in-app-purchase was successful and will successfully process outside of the sandbox.

Your app status will not affect your in-app-purchases if you are running in the sandbox, however, you should not run IAP tests unless your status on your next version is **Waiting for Upload**.

Hope this helps,

David

Sources: Apple MKStoreKit Documentation; I have **2** approved apps on the App Store with in-app-purchases running smoothly.